# How do I stop NSURLRequest from timeout after 10 seconds, other than using initialiser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I create a NSURLRequest to access Twitter user streams through the TwitterKit API, like so:

```
    let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
        "GET",
        URL: "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json",
        parameters: parameters,
        error: &error)
```

This means that I don't get to use the usual initialiser, and have access to the timeout interval. So the timeout interval is set to the default of 10 seconds, and it's readonly after initialising.

When I start the connection like this:

```
self.urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
self.urlConnection!.start()
```

I get results through delegate methods for the first 10 seconds, then it cuts off.

My way around this now is to re-start the connection again every time it cuts off, but that's not in any way ideal, and obviously runs the risk of missing any data that comes in the downtime.

If I try this, I simply get an error:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: {
    (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

It returns an empty response and data, with the error `The request timed out.`

How do I get this streaming response, without the URL request timing out after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Twitter API, but if that method returns
an `NSURLRequest` then you can make a mutable copy and modify it:

```
let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(...)
let newRequest = request.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
newRequest.timeoutInterval = ...
```